# New ASUS desktop seems to go into a sort of sleep mode overnight

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

I have a brand new ASUS desktop (model G11CD0 Intel Core i5 16 GB, NVIDIA GTX1060, 512 GB SSD, 1 TB HDD.

I like to leave the thing on overnight or for days at a time so I can use my Team Viewer to access files when I am away from home.

The problem is it seems to go into some sort of sleep mode.   The machine is obviously still on as evidenced by power to the lighted keyboard, and the lit case accent lights, as well as a lit power button.  It will not accept ANY input from the mouse or keyboard.  The screen is completely black except for a pause sign in the lower right corner.

The only way to bring it back is to hold the power key for about 10 seconds and do a full shut down.

I have tried every Windows 10 setting I know to disable any sleep modes.  My son the computer genius is certain it is a Windows/ software thing. I want to make sure its not hardware - in case I need to send it back I need to do it within warranty period.

Anyone have any ideas? Possibly a sleep/hibernate setting I missed somewhere? Maybe in the bios or something.  Anyway to wake it up without rebooting?

All answers are welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: No. This doesn't sound like a sleep/hibernate issue. The system is freezing up. Could be hardware or software. But not a sleep/hibernate issue.

Comment: This sounds more like a deep sleep/hibernation thing. To really make sure it's off, open the command prompt as admin and type the command `powercfg -h off` then hit enter. Test that out and see what happens.

Comment: There is also one other obscure setting I can think of. Go into the device manager. For your keyboard and mouse, right click on each one and select properties and then the power management tab. From there make sure that *Allow the computer to turn off this device* IS NOT checked and make sure that *Allow this device to wake the computer* IS checked.

Comment: Hmm. tried the powercfg -h off and it wouldn't accept it. Gave me the following message: